# How can I avoid code repetition with enums in C#?

Tags: c#, dynamic, enums, repeat

I am populating three list boxes with values from three corresponding enums. Is there some way to avoid having three separate-but-very-similar methods? Here's what I have now:

```
    private void PopulateListBoxOne()
    {
        foreach (EnumOne one in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumOne)))
        {
            lstOne.Items.Add(one);
        }
        lstOne.SelectedIndex         = 0;
    }

    private void PopulateListBoxTwo()
    {
        foreach (EnumTwo two in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumTwo)))
        {
            lstTwo.Items.Add(two);
        }
        lstTwo.SelectedIndex         = 0;
    }

    private void PopulateListBoxThree()
    {
        foreach (EnumThree three in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumThree)))
        {
            lstThree.Items.Add(three);
        }
        lstThree.SelectedIndex         = 0;
    }
```

But I'd instead prefer to have one method (which I could call three times) looking something like:

```
private void PopulateListBox(ListBox ListBoxName, Enum EnumName)
{
    // ... code here!
}
```

I'm quite an inexperienced programmer, so although I did search, I wasn't quite sure what I was searching for. Apologies if this has been answered before; I'd be equally grateful to be shown an existing answer. Thanks!

Comment: Wudzik's answer worked right out of the box. Thanks - a beautiful start to my Stack Overflow experience! (Thanks for the other answers too, although I haven't yet tried them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass enum type to your method

```
private void PopulateListBox(ListBox ListBoxName, Type EnumType)
{
    foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(EnumType))
    {
        ListBoxName.Items.Add(value);
    }
    ListBoxName.SelectedIndex=0;
}
```

so call it like:

```
PopulateListBox(lstThree,typeof(EnumThree));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a generic method:

```
private void PopulateListBox<TEnum>(ListBox listBox, bool clearBeforeFill, int selIndex) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enum type");

    if(clearBeforeFill) listBox.Items.Clear();
    listBox.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(TEnum))); // or listBox.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<object>().ToArray());

    if(selIndex >= listBox.Items.Count)
        throw new ArgumentException("SelectedIndex must be lower than ListBox.Items.Count");

    listBox.SelectedIndex = selIndex;
}
```

How you use it:

```
PopulateListBox<EnumThree>(lstThree, true, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
    private List<T> PopulateList<T>()
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        foreach (T e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
        {
            list.Add(e);
        }
        return list;
    }
```